# Writing a RESTful Angular login function only if it has the necessary User Role

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

```
this.login = function(credentials) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        url: "https://api.parse.com/1/login",
        headers: {
            "X-Parse-Application-Id": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.APP_ID,
            "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": PARSE_CREDENTIALS.REST_API_KEY,
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        params: {
            "username": credentials.username.toLowerCase(),
            "password": credentials.password,
            where: { 
                "role": {
                    //"objectId": "ADMIN_ID",
                    //"objectId": "EDITOR_ID"
                }
            }
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        Session.create(data.sessionToken,data.objectId, data.role);
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        deferred.reject("error")
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I want to write this function to only return a success if the login credentials match a user with either the id of the Admin user role, or the Editor user role.

The Parse.com pointer object for the Role class looks like this:

```
role: {
    __type: "Pointer",
    className: "_Role",
    objectId: "/*id goes here*/"
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to accomplish this? I have 3 user roles. But only want two of them to be able to login in this particular situation.

Comment: uhm.... that check needs to be done server-side, otherwise a malicious user can just set a breakpoint and remove the role restriction.

Comment: My research was starting to lead me in that direction. Thanks. I'll give you credit for an answer.